# Date shortcut inserts TOMORROW instead of today?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Chrome on Mac.  The keyboard shortcut for inserting the date into a cell is <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> but for some reason it always inserts *tomorrow's* date, not today's.  My computer's clock is definitely set correctly, and it's many hours before midnight so it wouldn't likely be a timezone oddity either.

So why is this happening?  Bug?  Misunderstanding of the feature?

Answer (score 4):

The solution as posted in a previous comment (since removed apparently) was to check the `Spreadsheet Settings` in the `file` menu and ensure it was set to the correct timezone.  It was not, so that's why the date was off.